# Expandable UItableview content height are different during expanded or collapsed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created an expandable tableview by separated with multiple sections. Because this tableview is inside a container view, so I need to update the container view size every time the tableview expand or collapse.

I update the container size with tableview.contentsize.height but I found out the content size are different when its expanded or collapsed.

For e.g, lets say there are 4 sections, if I collapse the 3rd and 4th sections the tableview will return me height of 200. Meanwhile if I expand the table just 1st and 2nd section while 3rd and 4th is collapsed, the content size height is more than 200.

I find it very frustrated why the program is giving me such confusing information, because I need a proper content size height to update the container view. Anyone here can enlighten me?

Comment: Without more information I can't tell, but I'm suspicious that you either don't need to resize the containerView, or you don't understand how UIScrollViews work.

Comment: @PeejWeej I am too new to swift, i found out there is UItableviewautomaticdimension function. One question, a tableview inside a containderview, then this container is inside a static tableview cell, can it be auto resize based on the contents?

Comment: You have a `ContainerView` _inside_ of a `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: @PeejWeej yes, i am maintaining a legacy code so I cant make too much changes now. Is there any way to dynamically change the size of the container inside a static table cell?

Comment: Usually that's not even allowed, but maybe it works with static cells. If you have all the constraints setup to auto-size, you can set `containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on your `ContainerView`s and it should resize based on it's layout constraints.

Comment: @PeejWeej seems can not, the container view will just not showing up on the table view. I implement UItableviewautomaticdimension. It can be shown up if I give it a height, thats why I so eager to get the contents height and to update the container view height

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of content size that you've described is correct. If you want to know the height of the `UITableView` you should look at it's frame, not at it's content size.

I'm not sure why you need a container view for the table view, you can layout it like the simple `UIView`, then you'll have one less problem, just change the tableView frame.

**Update**:

After reading comments i see that you want tableView inside of tableViewCell. Most part you'll have to do yourself, but i can help you with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Try adding this to your viewController:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 44//approximate cell height
 }
```

The main thing is to set constraints properly in interface builder. And remember that constraints won't change the height of the cell on builder, you may have to do it yourself in the Size inspector. Anyway if you won't - it will be resized during the build.

Comment: bro, but frame.height always return the maximum value of the table, no matter collapse or expand the height number is not changing

Comment: depends on how you collapse or expand tableView, please add to your question some of your code, i'll try to help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `contentSize` try calculating the height on your own. It'll be much easier if every cell is the same height. Let's say they are all 50 height and there is 1 row in section 1 and 3 rows in section 2. (1 + 3) * 50 = container height. Obviously if you have sections and insets you will also need to include that into your calculation.

If your cells are different heights, just call the table views cell height delegate to get the relevant height.

If this doesn't work for you then please be more descriptive and add some code.